# How to dynamically change name of StreamResource in FileDownloadWrapper

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to change the name of file which are downloaded after button click.

So I created the button and wraped it using FileDownloadWrapper

```
private Component createDownloadButton() {
    Button downloadButton = new Button(VaadinIcon.DOWNLOAD);
    FileDownloadWrapper buttonWrapper = new FileDownloadWrapper(new StreamResource("export_" + LocalDateTime.now() + ".pdf",
        () -> createDataForPdf()));
    buttonWrapper.wrapComponent(downloadButton );

    return buttonWrapper;
}
```

The problem is, that the file has the same name "between clicks"

***Example:***

I clicked on button `12.october.2022` at `17:00` - file name was `export_2022-10-12T17_00_00.000000000.pdf`

I clicked on button again at `17:05`, but the name of file was still
`export_2022-10-12T17_00_00.000000000.pdf`

Is there any solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any official way of doing this, but there is a workaround. The `StreamResource` has a `getHeaders()` method that you can use to set a custom value of the `Content-Disposition` header which the browser uses to determine the file name.

The general structure of the workaround is something like this:

```java
new StreamResource("not used", () -> createDataForPdf()) {
  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(super.getHeaders());
    String name = "some-name-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt";
    headers.put("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+name+"\"");
    return headers;
  }
};
```